# Spring + Hibernate4: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

I have a spring/hibernate application when using Hibernate3 all it works fine but it does not when migrating to Hibernate4 with the same configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

It works within Hibernate3 without `@Transactional` annotation but does not within Hibernate4 I got this exception 
`HibernateException("Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread")`

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Demo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which basically tells you that your configuration was actually already wrong from the start, but there where some additional *hacks* in the hibernate3 support to make things work. Let me guess you use a `<component-scan />`?

Comment: Yes I did, what's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Don't use the **same** `<component-scan />` in both the `ContextLoaderListener` configuration and `DispatcherServlet` configuration. If you do that it will lead to duplicating bean instances one with proper transactional config and one without (generally in the `DispatcherServlet`) and the latter will be used by the controllers, hence no transactions, hence the error.

Comment: I my case I have just DispatcherServlet configuration file context-servlet.xml
` <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/context-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Comment: You don't have a `ContextLoaderListener`? Please add your `web.xml`.

Comment: yes I have  <listener>
  <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: Please add it to the question not as comments!. Yours is even worse as you are loading the whole application twice! Which will lead to strange to debug transactional issues, memory issues etc.

Comment: What is unclear to me is do you actually added `@Transactional` or not?

Comment: I've added @Transactional to avoid the exception already mentioned

Comment: Now it is even more confusing, do you or do you not have the error still?

Comment: With hibernate3 it works without Transactional annotation but when using hibernate4 we have to add Transactional annotationto be worked. I'm wondering if i can work with hibernate4 without Transactional annotation.

Comment: No you cannot and please rephrase your question as that wasn't clear. As mentioned the hibernate3 support contains several hacks to make things work. Those hacks aren't needed basically after hibernate 3.0.1 but where still there. The hibernate 4 support cleaned that up and removed the unnecessary hacks, so no it isn't possible at least not with a plain `SessionFactory` it would work with a `HibernateTemplate` but that isn't recommended to use and is merely a migration strategy from template to plain hibernate.

Comment: Is HibernateTemplate not recommended? what is the alternative? am I have to add `@Transactional` overall my DAOs?

Comment: Your service layer and not your dao layer should e transactional. Hibernate was needed in the pre hibernate 3.0.1 era, after that it is recommended to use a plain `SessionFactory` with `getCurrentSession`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is helpful